# Why javascript for loop prints only last element

Tags: javascript

I am testing below javascript for loop.

```
var items = ['one','two','three']
for(var i=0, l=items.length; i < l; i++){
    console.log(i);
    items[i];
}
```

And the out put is as follows.

```
0
1
2
"three"
```

Why only the last item is getting printed if it is not enclosed in console.log?

EDIT1: I apologize for the the initial copy paste mess up. I updated the code. And if I print items[i] as part of the console log it prints all three items but not outside.

Comment: don't you want to write 'items[i]'  ?

Comment: That code will give you a reference error.

Comment: What is `item`? Oh, btw, never seen a question downvoted this fast. I haven't done it though.

Comment: @Kaf not just this question, someone went and downvoted all my previous questions and answers too. I do not understand why such hatred?

Comment: Don't worry, if someone has targeted you unfairly, SO will sort things out for you within 24 hours [according to this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do).

Comment: @Nu2Overflow wow that is messed up. Well to your edited question, off course it doesn't print items[i] when it is not in console.log because  items[i] does nothing. With console.log the value on the given index(i) is logged in the console. Ps I have not un-1 this question because it is now more clear after your edit.

Comment: @mariomario - The above code is an example. In my actual code, I have an array of "<a href>" elements. And I am trying iterate over the array and triggering click event on each element using loop similar to above. But it fires the click event only on last element and ignores all previous ones.

Comment: Then I doubt that it has anything to do with a for loop but rather something with events. If you could recreate it then people could anwser your question. Maybe also use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show what goes wrong.

Comment: This is actually a pretty neat question, which took me some time to wrap my head around. Definitly worth an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is per se nothing wrong with your loop. What you are wrong about is, considering `"three"` as a output.

`"Three"` is just the last value of this expression.

If you would write

```
var items = ['one','two','three'];
for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
    i; // i itself just calls the variable and does nothing with it. 
       // Test it with the developer console on Google Chrome and you'll notice a
       // different prefix before the line
}
```

there would be no output, because only console.log() generates actual output. If you want to output i and the value in the array at the position i your code would be:

```
var items = ['one','two','three'];
for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```